# Runaway process named "data5"

Tags: processes

I have an issue on an Android TV device from Amlogic. As you can see below there are three important processes: `.amlogic.dvb.service` and `com.amlogic.dvb`. These processes are related to the UI of the TV player and the controller of the TV stream.

`data5` is very confusing. It does not steal the CPU all of the time. However, when it does, it causes the TV display to become distorted (because there is no longer sufficient CPU power to render correctly, I assume).

Does anyone know what the process `data5` is? I think it is probably part of Android itself, however I have yet to find anything on Google relating to it.

```
User 9%, System 86%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
User 53 + Nice 4 + Sys 525 + Idle 21 + IOW 3 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 2 = 608
  PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
24786  0  48% S    25 741952K  37912K  fg system   .amlogic.dvb.service
 1541  0  42% S     1      0K      0K     root     data5
24743  1   0% S    27 814488K  71752K  fg system   com.amlogic.dvb
 1540  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     aml_nftld
25319  1   0% R     1   1228K    520K     shell    top
```

Comment: It's very likely to be specific to your device. Has it always had this problem? If so, you probably need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: I thought so too, but they do not recognize the process either. I will get them to dig deeper. It exists after a clean firmware flash, so it is definitely to do with the firmware.